# Vue 3 - How to disable adding trailing slash?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

Problem statement **:** Vue app changes the URL after loading the scripts and adds a slash to the end. This only happens for routes where the path matches `/`.

I have the server configured like this **:**

```
/game(.*) => Vue 3 App  
anything else => reverse proxy
```

My router **:**

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: () => import('../views/Home.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/:pathMatch(.*)',
        component: () => import('../views/NotFound.vue'),
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory('/game/'),
    routes,
    strict: true
});
```

What's happening **:**
If I request `http://localhost/game`, the URL in the address bar changes to `http://localhost/game/`. I don't understand why this is happening. What I know for sure is that it's Vue that does it, not the server.

Screen **:**

[image]

If I add something else to the URL, for example `http://localhost/game/notfound`, then the slash will not be added to the end.

**UPD**
Additionally, I show my *config.vue.js* **:**

```
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version;

module.exports = {
    publicPath: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/game' : '/'),
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api': {
                target: 'http://app:'+process.env.APP_PORT,
                ws: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            },
        }
    },
    lintOnSave: 'default',
    productionSourceMap: false
};
```

And content *console.log(process.env)* **:**

```
{
    "NODE_ENV": "production",
    "VUE_APP_ENV": "dev",
    "VUE_APP_VERSION": "1.0.0",
    "BASE_URL": "/game/"
}
```

Comment: Try removing the '/' in: `history: createWebHistory('/game/'),` .. change it to `history: createWebHistory('/game'),`

Comment: @MuhammadAmmar unfortunately it didn't change anything

Comment: I've got the same issue and it's messing with my SEO. Vue router automatically adding a slash onto the public facing pages so the `/contact.html` becomes `/contact.html/`. Google is seeing it as duplicates and wanting to mark `/contact.html/` as the canonical version so there are no sitelinks under our search result. It's a real headache.